# I can't get my Kivy program to write an Image to gallery on an andriod phone

Tags: android, python-3.x, image, kivy, android-permissions

The APK file installs fine, and the non writing to gallery version works fine. But when the write to gallery version runs, the app wont start at all. (the program creates a file in the gallery upon startup)

The main function of the app is to pixelate a QR code type image from black and white to colour.

Has any one found an answer to this, or know of where there is an example of how to get KIVY to write an image file to gallery for android 13.

Regards
Tony

We tried chatCTP. We have tried different phones, etc.  We have not been able to get an image file to save in gallery.

Comment: You can not write files to the gallery ss there is no gallery on an Android device. You can instead write files to several storage locations. There are so called Gallery apps that show images from some locations. And nowadays there is Photos/Fotos app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks very much.  We are going to close this now, and follow up with a different  post.